# prevent from empty binding value in spring boot application properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot, binding, application.properties

i got something like that...

in my spring boot application properties

```
proxy.for.US7743411016.instruCurrency=EUR
proxy.for.US7743411016.proxyId=PROXY0001
proxy.for.US7743411016.proxyCurrency=EUR
proxy.for.ISIN0002.instruCurrency=EUR
proxy.for.ISIN0002.proxyId=PROXY0002
proxy.for.ISIN0002.proxyCurrency=EUR
```

in my configuration Class..

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("proxy.for")
public Map<String, Proxyfication> proxies() {
   return new TreeMap<>();
}
```

and of course a POJO like this..

```
public class Proxyfication {
  String         proxyId;
  String         proxyCurrency;
  String         instruCurrency;
```

My question is : how to unauthorize incomplete binding like..

```
proxy.for.US7743411016.instruCurrency=   <====== empty
proxy.for.US7743411016.proxyId=PROXY0001
proxy.for.US7743411016.proxyCurrency=EUR
```

Is there a smart solution via annotation, or other ?

IN fact, the only way i found was to introduce an exception in my POJO setter.

```
  public void setInstruCurrency(String instruCurrency) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(instruCurrency)) {
      logger.error("empty or null instruCurrency attribute provided.");
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("empty or null instruCurrency forbidden.");
    }

    this.instruCurrency = instruCurrency;
  }
```

a little bit inappropriate or heavy isn't it ?

Comment: You can use validation annotations. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.validation

Comment: i tried but it didn't have any effect :-(

Comment: Only adding annotations (the API) doesn't do anything, you need to add `spring-boot-starter-validation` to your class path and put and `@NotEmpty` on that field. Another thing is you might need to add `@Valid` to the `@Bean` or nested `Map` as what you are doing is actually a bit weird .